# Data always log 0 if log the length when fetch data from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from firestore, my workflow like this:

- Create an array, then log the id of collection of 'users'
- Check if user exist by check if the value exist on the above array , if exist, then login directly, if not create new collection on firestore

But don't know how when i log the data, it show correctly, but if i log the length, it always show 0, and of course the comparison show false everytime

Here is the code

```
export default function Login(props: LoginI) {
  const user = useRef<User>();

  const [userExist, setUserExist] = useState<boolean>(false);
  let ListUser: any[] = [];
 

  const {} = props;
  const addNew = () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(user.current?.user?.email)
      .set({
        userInfo: { ...user.current },
        note: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(),
      });
    // .then(() => console.log("success"));
  };
  const getUser = async () => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .get()
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((snapshot) => {
          ListUser.push(snapshot.id);   ====> //add user to local array
        });
      });
  };
  async function signIn() {
    // Get the users ID token

    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

    user.current = userInfo;
    getUser();
    console.log("firebaseList", ListUser);  ==> always return value
    console.log("firebaseList", ListUser.length); ==> alway return 0

    // ListUser = ListUser.concat(user.current.user?.email);

    ListUser.forEach((item) => {
      console.log("item", item);
      if (item === user.current?.user?.email) {
        setUserExist(true);
        return;
      }
      return;
    });
    console.log(userExist);
    

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      userInfo.idToken
    );

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          signIn();
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Login</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is the pic of this [image]

I don't know where i get mess up, please help, thank you so much

Comment: The only thing I see is that you didn't `await` your call to `getUser`, which is an async function. It could cause race conditions issues.

Comment: I don't get it @GaëtanBoyals, i tried to not call async function  but the result still return 0 when i log, but if i log the data it return the real data

Comment: Try to put `await getUser();` instead of simply `getUser();`, line 71 in `login.tsx` and see if it works. If not, I can't help more because I don't see any problem.

Comment: OMG it work !!!!!!!!! @GaëtanBoyals

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Sounds like an answer Gaëtan    Can you post it below, so that the system also can see that the question was answered?

Comment: Sure thing! I'm on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a distant database in your `getUser` function (in this case, `firebase`), a network request which will inevitably take longer to execute than your local code.

This leads to an issue called **race condition**. The code below your call to `getUser()` *might* be executed before the network request is completed, resulting in unpredictable behavior.

To prevent this, you need to wait for the network call to complete before treating any further instructions. Whether you do it via `callbacks`, `promises` or `async/await` syntax is up to your preferences but since you already use `async/await`, you need to `await` your call to `getUser()`, below is your code with the correction:

```
export default function Login(props: LoginI) {
  const user = useRef<User>();

  const [userExist, setUserExist] = useState<boolean>(false);
  let ListUser: any[] = [];
 

  const {} = props;
  const addNew = () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(user.current?.user?.email)
      .set({
        userInfo: { ...user.current },
        note: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(),
      });
    // .then(() => console.log("success"));
  };
  const getUser = async () => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .get()
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((snapshot) => {
          ListUser.push(snapshot.id);   ====> //add user to local array
        });
      });
  };
  async function signIn() {
    // Get the users ID token

    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

    user.current = userInfo;
    // the line below was missing an await
    await getUser();
    console.log("firebaseList", ListUser);  ==> always return value
    console.log("firebaseList", ListUser.length); ==> alway return 0

    // ListUser = ListUser.concat(user.current.user?.email);

    ListUser.forEach((item) => {
      console.log("item", item);
      if (item === user.current?.user?.email) {
        setUserExist(true);
        return;
      }
      return;
    });
    console.log(userExist);
    

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      userInfo.idToken
    );

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          signIn();
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Login</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```